# C++ UDP Socket port multiplexing

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, multiplexing

How can I create a client UDP socket in C++ so that it can listen on a port which is being listened to by another application? In other words, how can I apply port multiplexing in C++?

Comment: Multiplexing is only useful if the other end of the socket is expecting muxed data (unless you are trying to "forge" the data that the other end expects).

Comment: I guess I must explain the scenario a little better. I have a application running on port 5000. I want to listen on the same port, so that I can receive and parse all the packets that the app is receiving. I thought that I can use SO_REUSEADDR option for binding the socket, but this WAITS for the original application to close before my program receives packets on the same port. I hope the question and the desired behaviour is clear now. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to listen on only one port

You can do that with a sniffer. Just ignore the packets from different ports.

> I might need to stop it from sending out some particular packets, because my program will send it instead of the original application

Okay, here I suggest you to discard sniffers, and use a [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) technique.

You'll need to rely on a PREROUTING firewall rule to *divert* the packets to a "*proxy*" application. Assuming UDP, Linux, iptables, and the "*proxy*" running on the same host, here's what the "*proxy*" actually needs to do:

**1.** Add the firewall rule to *divert* the packets (do it manually, if you prefer):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i <iface> -p <proto> --dport <dport>
    -j REDIRECT --to-port <newport>
```

**2.** Bind and listen on `<newport>`.

**3.** Relay all the traffic between the 2 endpoints (client, and original destination). If you're running the "*proxy*" on a different host, use [getsockopt](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getsockopt.html) with `SO_ORIGINAL_DST` to retrieve the original destination address.

It might sound tricky, but... yeah, that's because it's a bit tricky :-)
Consult your firewall documentation if my assumption diverges.

Answer (score 2):

This is just packet sniffing like `tcpdump` or `snoop`, open up a raw socket and pull everything from the wire and filter as you require.  You will probably want to use [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) to make things a little easier.

Without administrator or super-user privileges you will need the target application to open ports with `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT` as appropriate for the platform.  The caveat being you can only receive broadcast and multicast packets, unicast packets are delivered to the first open socket.

Comment: Ok. So, in your opinion, the only other alternative is using libpcap to sniff every packet on a network interface and then filter out the packets for that particular port. I was thinking that since these are UDP packets (connection-less), it should not have been a problem to passively/actively send/receive the packet on the same port.

Comment: I've tried, Linux only delivers to the first socket, it does not multiplex unicast packets.  Other platforms may but are unlikely to be different for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* multiplexing - that term is reserved for handling I/O on multiple channels in the same process and where things like `select(2)` and `poll(2)` are most useful.

What you are asking for is [**multicast**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast). [Here](http://ntrg.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2/multicast/antony/) is the basic example.

Note that IP reserves a special range of addresses (a.k.a. groups) for multicasting. These get mapped to special ethernet addresses. The listener(s) would have to *join* the multicast group, while sender does not have to, it just sends as usual.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a software app running on port 5000, and I cannot modify that application so that it joins any multicast group or likewise. I want to listen on the same port so that my code can parse all the packets received by that application. I had a notion that this was called 'port multiplexing', but I am unable to find a proper example for the same.

Comment: Then get the Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/), sniff the packets, dump into a file, and have a go at it.

Comment: I am using wireshark to look at the packets offline, but I have to write a C++ program which sniffs or listens on a particular port and not on all the ports, and it cannot be offline. I can use libpcap library, but like I said I want to listen on only one port, and I might need to stop it from sending out some particular packets, because my program will send it instead of the original application!! I am not sure if I am confusing you a lot :)

Comment: pcap allows you to filter what you listen to, see here http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.htm