# UDP MITM by adding rules to iptables

Tags: c++, udp, iptables

In [C++ UDP Socket port multiplexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878303/c-udp-socket-port-multiplexing), I found that using DNAT PREROUTING, I can redirect the packets for a particular UDP port and listen to packets being received on it.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i <iface> -p <proto> --dport <dport>
    -j REDIRECT --to-port <newport>
```

Unfortunately this works ONLY for packets **received** at this port. How can I get the packets being **sent from this port**?

Comment: :) I tried using prerouting with -sport.. doesn't work... I cannot use using postrouting -j SNAT in any way. How else can I do it?

Comment: Why can't you use SNAT? That seems to be the way to do it.